# Spring-Boot Security use Roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, bearer-token, spring-boot-security

I have recently looked into Spring-Boot and wanted to make a registration and login form for my application.
I have watched a video and build my application around, what he said in the video.

The authentication works and a jwt token is generated. When I have a valid token, i can send requests to methods without getting a 403 response.

My question: My User Class has a Role, which is an enum (USER, ADMIN)

How can I configure my application to check what role the current User has and bind this role to certain methods?

Here is my Code:

*User Entity*

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "varchar(30)")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(60)")
    @Length(min = 8, max = 256)
    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String teamName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int overallScore;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int gameDayScore;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_players",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "player_id", nullable = false)}
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"users"})
    private List<Player> players;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Role Enum Class*

```
public enum Role{
    USER,
    ADMIN;
}
```

*JwtService*

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "b7acf8204b85ab7cec6e73b91f682677d642d328fdec7788e8cbff11ff1a5b22";

    public String extractUsername(String jwtToken) {
        return extractClaim(jwtToken, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String jwtToken, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllclaims(jwtToken);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateJwtToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSigningKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public String generateJwtToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateJwtToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public boolean isJwtTokenValid(String jwtToken, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(jwtToken);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isJwtTokenExpired(jwtToken);
    }

    private boolean isJwtTokenExpired(String jwtToken) {
        return extractExpiration(jwtToken).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String jwtToken) {
        return extractClaim(jwtToken, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllclaims(String jwtToken) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSigningKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSigningKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

}
```

*JwtAuthFilter*

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwtToken;
        final String userEmail;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isJwtTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

*SecurityConfig*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

*ApplicationConfig*

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The *AuthenticationController*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterRequestDto request) {
        return authenticationService.registerUser(request);
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticateUser(@RequestBody AuthRequestDto request) {
        return authenticationService.authenticateUser(request);
    }
}
```

The *DemoController* where i want the "sayHelloAdmin" method to be only accessed by an admin and the "sayHelloUser" method by user and admin:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/demo-controller")
public class DemoController {


    @GetMapping(value = "/admin")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sayHelloAdmin() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello from admin endpoint");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sayHelloUser() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello from user endpoint");
    }

}
```

and the *AuthenticationService*

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authManager;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> registerUser(RegisterRequestDto request) {

        request.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()));

        User user = userMapper.registerRequestDtoToUser(request);

        user.setRole(Role.USER);
        user.setGameDayScore(0);
        user.setOverallScore(0);
        user.setPlayers(new ArrayList<>());

        userRepository.save(user);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateJwtToken(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .jwtToken(jwtToken)
                .build(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticateUser(AuthRequestDto request) {
        authManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword())
        );
        var user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateJwtToken((user));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .jwtToken(jwtToken)
                .build(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

*AuthRequestDto* and *RegisterRequestDto* are almost identical to the user entity but with fewer attributes.

Thanks in advance for your help!

sorry for the many codeblocks^^

cya!

~ Max

Comment: General way to do this is to add Roles to the jwt token and then use an annotation like @PreAuthorize on the controller methods. I think you need to add the roles to the authToken in the filter so that principal has these roles.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-check-user-role check this out.
/@PreAuthorize will probably do the trick as mentioned by @TomeKK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a fully working solution. Just extend a customizer

```
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(...).hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(...).hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(...).hasAuthority("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(...).hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
```

Comment: Like @TomekK suggested it does indeed make sense to add roles to the token, so you don't have to load user from DB with each request - the data in JWT token is trusted as long as signature is correct.

Comment: int the (...) part i put in the paths right? and thats it? the http methods are assigned to the roles then? or do i need annotations in the controller class?
and is tehre a difference between hasRole and hasAuthority?

Comment: If you define the customizer in configuration, you don't need the annotations. Generally speaking - roles are authorities as well. The difference is how Spring checks them. `hasRole('ADMIN')` will check if there is `ROLE_ADMIN` value in authorities. `hasAuthority('ADMIN')` will check if there is `ADMIN` value in authorities.

Comment: Prefix `ROLE_` is also configurable